# Rally multi select dropdown

Tags: rally

Is there a way to create multi select dropdown in Rally for user story's Schedule state fields. I want to filter user stories based on their schedule state.

I have gone through the doc and Rallyfieldpicker seems perfect for this but it is unclear to me how to filter user story fields. 
I've tried the following to no effect:

```
       {
        xtype: 'rallyfieldpicker',
        autoExpand: true,
        modelType: 'userstory',
        fieldLabel: 'Filter by Schedule State',
        filterFieldName: 'ScheduleState'
       }
```

Could someone help me with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rallyfieldvaluecombobox has a [multiSelect](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0/doc/#!/api/Rally.ui.combobox.FieldValueComboBox-cfg-multiSelect) config property. There are no checkboxes in front of each selection to indicate that multiselection is allowed, but it supports multi-selection nevertheless.

```
this.add({
   xtype: 'rallyfieldvaluecombobox',
   model: 'UserStory',
   multiSelect: true,
   field: ScheduleState,
    listeners: {
        select: this._getFilter,
        ready: this._getFilter,
        scope: this
    }
});
```

See an example of a custom app that uses it in [this github repo](https://github.com/RallyCommunity/multiple-selections)

Comment: Nick, Thanks for providing the example. The app I' m working on is very similar to the custom app except that I want to list userstories and filter them based on Schedule State and Target Release. I have replaced grid storeConfig model to 'userstory' and updated filter properties. But I don't see any items in the grid. Am I missing something?